# StackOverflowError during Building workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, seam

please take a look at this error, how can i fix it?

An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Would like to +1 for asking a question about a stack overflow, but to tell the truth, your question is pretty vague and needs more detail.

Comment: +1 for the desire to +1 about a stack overflow. Am I getting too redundant? if we get 6 more comments doing the same thing will it...overflow? God, someone stop me!

Comment: What are the plugins that you're using?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the `.metadata/.log` file in your workspace directory. It should contain the full stack trace for the exception which may give you a better idea about what is happening. If not, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to reply.. I just got this issue and I tried commenting the code on which I was working when error occurred and Build workspace. This solve the issue.